# How to make the 2 sheets work with filter action?

Tags: tableau-desktop, action-filter

I have 2 dashboards with city and city group filters. In the 1st dashboard when I click on a specific city name it has to redirect to the 2nd dashboard and the dashboard needs to filter according to the selected city.

Issue: In the 2nd dashboard, it is fixing the city from the previous dashboard action. When I select other cities in the 2nd dashboard it is gives me a blank.

I tried action filters to swap the sheets and used the filtered action. And I tried to add refresh button in the 2nd dashboard to clear the previous dashboard action filter. But it looks very clumsy(includes all the city details).